# Return Value Column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The stored procedure below works correctly as expected. Returning True if "FleetBarcode" exists and False if it doesn't.

However, when it returns it it displays it as below

```
(no column name)
     True
```

**My problem is** I need the "No Column Name" part to have a defined column name. Tried the method below so far which gives the 'True' field an alias.

Thank you for your time.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[usp_getjobs]

@barcode as nvarchar(20)


as
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(
SELECT 
[FleetBarcode],
[Deleted]

FROM w_DeliveryItems


 WHERE FleetBarcode = @barcode
 AND Deleted != 1
)
THEN (SELECT  'True'  'Exist')
ELSE (SELECT 'False' 'Exist')


END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[usp_getjobs] @barcode AS NVARCHAR(20)
AS
    SELECT CASE
             WHEN EXISTS(SELECT [FleetBarcode],
                                [Deleted]
                         FROM   w_DeliveryItems
                         WHERE  FleetBarcode = @barcode
                                AND Deleted != 1) THEN 'True'
             ELSE 'False'
           END AS [Exist]
```

The alias needs to go on the outer `SELECT`.

Also for column aliasing it is more common to use square brackets than single quotes.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I never would have noticed that this late on in the afternoon!

Answer (score 3):

Get rid if the `SELECT`s in the `THEN`/`ELSE` blocks and use `AS` to give the column a name:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(
...
THEN 'True')
ELSE 'False')
END AS [Exist]  --<-- add name here
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[usp_getjobs]

@barcode as nvarchar(20)


as
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(
SELECT 
[FleetBarcode],
[Deleted]

FROM w_DeliveryItems


 WHERE FleetBarcode = @barcode
 AND Deleted != 1
)
THEN (SELECT  'True'  'Exist')
ELSE (SELECT 'False' 'Exist')


END AS [Your Column Name]
```